# Pasar de un df a una matriz

Tags: python, pandas

Hola estoy trabajando con python (pandas) y necesito lo siguiente:

Tengo este df:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quiero llegar a un df que tenga como columna cada producto, como fila cada fecha y dentro el valor de las ventas para esa fecha/producto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: sería perfecto si pusieras los datos como texto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que quieres es hacer un *pivot* de tu *DataFrame*. Replicando un poco tu *DataFrame*

```py
cols = ["Fecha","Nproduct","Ventas"]
data = [
        ["sep-18","producto2","181309"],
        ["sep-18","producto5","88888"],
        ["sep-19","producto6","99998"],
        ["sep-19","producto10","10088"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns= cols)
```

Los *DataFrames* tiene un método llamado `pivot`que nos permiten hacer esta operación, solo tenemos que indicarle cual columna serán los índices, cuales las columnas y cuales los valores.

```py
df_change = df.pivot(index="Fecha", columns="Nproduct", values="Ventas")
print(df_change)
```

No te asustes si vez valores `NaN`, pues son normales al no haber datos, luego los puedes reemplazar o borrar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que buscas hacer es común en manejo de base de datos, es conocido como "funciones de agregación". Es cuando buscas aplicar una función no para cada fila o para cada columna, sino para un subconjunto de datos.

En este caso creas un subconjunto al agrupar por productos con el modulo `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` [ver más](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html), luego aplicas una función a cada subconjunto en este caso sumar `sum` (ver más funciones de agregación para pandas [funciones de agregación](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/groupby.html)).

```py
import pandas as pd
l = [[4,"productA", 12.3 ], [4,"productB",500], [3,"productA", 1],[3,"productB",3],[4,"productB",1]]
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=["fecha","producto", "valor"])

print(df)

result = df.groupby(by=["fecha","producto"]).sum()

print(result)


print(result.unstack(fill_value=0))
```

Salida de df:

```py
   fecha  producto  valor
0      4  productA   12.3
1      4  productB  500.0
2      3  productA    1.0
3      3  productB    3.0
4      4  productB    1.0
```

Salida de resultado:

```
                valor
fecha producto
3     productA    1.0
      productB    3.0
4     productA   12.3
      productB  501.0
```

Obtienes los productos en columnas al desempaquetar respecto a la suma:

```py
print(result.unstack(fill_value=0))
```

Salida:

```
producto productA productB
fecha
3             1.0      3.0
4            12.3    501.0
```

Comment: lo que se pide en la pregunta es pasar los valores de `NPRODUCT` a ser columnas (o headers)